# Step in Euler's rotation theorem

Tags: matrices, determinant, transformation, rotations

I have been examining the matrix proof for Euler's rotation theorem [on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_rotation_theorem#Matrix_proof). I have deduced every step up to proving that $\det (R - I) = 0$ for any rotation matrix R. However, I'm having difficulty understanding how to prove that $\det (R - I) = 0$ entails $(R - I)n = 0$. Any help in understanding this step would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The determinant is zero implies one of the eigenvalues is zero implies there is a eigenvector to the eigenvalue zero implies the eigenvector to 0 obeys $(R-I)n=\lambda*n=0*n=0$ and therefore $Rn=n$

Comment: I think the step I'm missing is how to prove that det(A) = 0 → An = 0.

Comment: I think the characteristic equation would be (R - I)n = 0. Looking at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_algebra#Eigenvalues_and_eigenvectors, the article says that for there to be nontrivial solutions to that equation, det(R − λI) = 0. But how do I prove that?

Comment: well if you look into determinants, you'll notice they are exactly then equals zero when the colums of the matrix A are linearly dependent, if you translate that into matrix form it means there is a vector x containing the multiples of the colums for which the addition of these multiples results in being zero. Aka $Ax=0$